# Where to install Composer and Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, mamp

I am using Symfony2 on my MacBook in local. So I have Symfony2 installed, MAMP installed and composer installed. But not sure if I installed them where I should install it. Would be very nice to have an overall files and folder plans to do it properly.

Here where I install Symfony and where I have composer:

**My symfony2 is here:**

```
Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/
```

**this file: composer.json is in Symfony**

```
Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/composer.json
```

**And composer.phar and again composer.json is in here:**

```
username/MyWebSite/bin/composer/composer.phar
-------------------------------/path/composer.json
```

(where should I put my symfony file and my composer files? What should I change (configuration) so that my website still working on localhost if I change something?

Comment: What? Composer makes the directory structure for you. Where you decide the project lives is your own discretion. Just make sure you set your `docroot` to `web/` within the Symfony folder. _Do not move the `composer.json` file around as it is relatively based to the `vendors` folder._ Again, `composer.phar` can be placed wherever you want it to be, but if you don't want to install it globally, it can stay right where it is.

Comment: OK, but then how does composer knows where Symfony is? is there any file where the location of symfony is set? (so if I want to change where my symfony files I can also change it) same about MAMP. how does symfony knows where MAMP and my tables are?

Comment: Composer looks for a `composer.json` file wherever you execute `composer` commands. It's the location of that JSON file that allows Composer to know "where Symfony is." No, there's no file that stores the location of Symfony. As long as you move the entire folder and its contents, the integrity of the project will be preserved (similar to how the hidden `.git` folder is stored within a project folder.) Symfony knows database settings from the `app/config/parameters.yml` file that was generated during `composer install`.

Comment: ok so in my case I have anyway 2 composer.json file. what if I delete the one in username/MyWebsite/bin/composer/path and leave composer.phar where it is? Under which file should I process this command: "php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" to install a new bundle?

Comment: Leave the one in `username/MyWebsite/bin/composer/path` alone or else you will find your composer breaking. It's the `composer.json` for Composer in general. You would run `php composer.phar update` from the working project folder.

Comment: this is what I tried. so my working project folder is Symfony: but when I write the command line php composer.phar update I got the following: **"Could not open input file: composer.phar"**

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to move Symfony project to an other folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054251/how-to-move-symfony-project-to-an-other-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put composer.json and composer.phar at the root of your Symfony folder (Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/).
Then "php composer.phar update" in the Command Line Interface.