# how to move Symfony project to an other folder?

Tags: symfony

I have started a project on Symfony2 and now I would like to change the place where I installed it in my files.

here where it is now:
**Application/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/**

What is I move the symfony file to
**user/myWebSiteProject/...**

by the way my composer is in:
**user/myWebsitePorject/bin/composer/composer.phar

---------------------------------------------/path/composer.json**

Can I do it just like it... move it just like any folder. or should I take into account some things...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the whole folder without any major issues. What you will need to do is to change any VirtualHosts you may have setup, You will need to update the DocumentRoot property.

You would normally find the file to update on a mac at: `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` depending on how your system is configured.

I'm presuming that your using Apache, Your VirtualHost should look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.symfony
    DocumentRoot "/user/myWebSiteProject/web"
    <Directory "/user/myWebSiteProject/web">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/local.symfony-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/local.symfony-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) should help with the configuration.

Comment: OK I moved it... but now got the following message when tring to acces my website app. **"The requested URL /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/mysite/modification_article/13 was not found on this server."**

Comment: if you are using the same (or very similar) vhost as above you shouldn't need the /Symfony/web/ part of the url. Ensure that the vhosts and rewrite modules are enabled in your apache config, restart apache and browse to http://local.symfony/app_dev.php in your browser. I've added a link in my answer to an official guide on setting up your web server.

Comment: OK I change Virtualhost to have similar as the one you write... but still got message **"The requested URL /app_dev.php/mywebsite was not found on this server."** when triing the URL http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php/mywebsite

Comment: why are you using localhost:8888? are you using apache?

Comment: yes I am using apache. I am in local (dev). what should be my url instead of localhost:8888/app_dev.php/mywebsite?

Comment: this is not working. I check again for vhosts and rewirte modules. I add the line  **"Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"** The other 2 lines where aleardy here: **LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so** AND **LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so** BUT the fact is the first line include... make apache not working any more. cannot restart it with that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69256/discussion-between-scriptable-and-aleqxs).

Comment: have you added something like 127.0.0.1 local.symfony to your /etc/hosts file